Maximum recursion depth exceeded in class | Python
I am writing a matrix class and I want to put a method of the same class in the attribute class
class Matrix:
    def __init__(
            self, 
            rows: int=None, 
            columns: int=None, 
            values: list[int | float | list[int | float]]=None
        ) -> None:
        self.__rows = 3 if not rows else (3 if rows <= 0 else rows)
        self.__columns = 3 if not columns else (3 if columns <= 0 else columns)
        self.__values = [
                            [
                                random.randint(-10, 10) 
                                for _ in range(self.__columns)
                            ]
                            for _ in range(self.__rows)
                        ] if not values and self.__rows != 1 \
                        else [
                            random.randint(-10, 10)
                            for _ in range(self.get_columns)
                        ] if self.__rows == 1 else values
        
        self.T = self.__transposition()
    
   
    
    def __transposition(self) -> typing.Self:
        return Matrix(
            self.__columns, 
            self.__rows, 
            [
                [
                    self.__values[j][i] 
                    for j in range(self.__rows)
                ] 
                for i in range(self.__columns)
            ]
        )
    
    
if name == 'main': 
    a = Matrix(rows=2)  
    print(a.T)

But there is a depth of recursion
File "Matrix.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.T = self.__transposition()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Matrix.py", line 47, in __transposition
    return Matrix(
           ^^^^^^^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

What can be done? I tried to pass it through the decorator of the static method, but nothing helped.

Matrix.__init__ calls Matrix.__transposition which calls Matrix.__init__ which calls Matrix.__transposition which calls ...

Remove self.T = ..., rename __transposition to T, and put @property in the line before. This way the transposition will only be calculated when necessary.

@BoppreH that still creates an infinite recursion

@DeepSpace No it doesn't. Added it as an answer now that I'm not writing from my phone.

Instead of evaluating the transpose when the matrix is created, evaluate it only when the property is accessed. You can do that with the @property decorator. And to avoid recalculating on every access, you can use @functools.cached_property
import typing, random
import functools

class Matrix:
    def __init__(
            self, 
            rows: int=None, 
            columns: int=None, 
            values: list[int | float | list[int | float]]=None
        ) -> None:
        self.__rows = 3 if not rows else (3 if rows <= 0 else rows)
        self.__columns = 3 if not columns else (3 if columns <= 0 else columns)
        self.__values = [
                            [
                                random.randint(-10, 10) 
                                for _ in range(self.__columns)
                            ]
                            for _ in range(self.__rows)
                        ] if not values and self.__rows != 1 \
                        else [
                            random.randint(-10, 10)
                            for _ in range(self.get_columns)
                        ] if self.__rows == 1 else values
   
    # Method renamed and decorator added.
    @functools.cached_property
    def T(self) -> typing.Self:
        return Matrix(
            self.__columns, 
            self.__rows, 
            [
                [
                    self.__values[j][i] 
                    for j in range(self.__rows)
                ] 
                for i in range(self.__columns)
            ]
        )
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    a = Matrix(rows=2)  
    print(a.T)

